# API return URL to localhost

Tags: php, api, localhost, returnurl

There are lot of answers in stackoverflow and outside too but none of them helped me. Actually, in my case I am using uniserver and created a virtual host for a project `ecommerce.dev`. I am working on a API where I need to set my return URL from where API redirect to my localhost. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436588/4807414) found on stackoverflow I tried this: `http://my-IP-address/verify-process` but could not help.

I need to set the return URL to this

```
<input type="hidden" name="RU" value="http://202.129.251.113/verify-process" />
```

When I don `ping 202.129.251.113` it respond me without packet loss.

When I checked for `vhosts.conf`, I could not find port number as it has `<VirtualHost *:${AP_PORT}>`.

So, Actual question is what may be possible solution to return to local host with from API?

Comment: Http uses port 80 by default.

Comment: Do you try to set return URL to `http://ecommerce.dev/verify-process`? I think you need to set URL for configured host.

Comment: @roman it returns as expected. URL is already configured