# redirect to a page after paypal payment success

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to redirect the user to certain page after the payment is successful.
[image]

I have this form, and when the user fills the details, I want to redirect the user to my page when the payment is successful. Is it possiblt?

Comment: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables.html#1231878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sample of paypal payment code.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="accounts@freelanceswitch.com">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">  
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://net.tutsplus.com/payment-complete/">    
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">  
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">  
</form>
```

Here `<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://net.tutsplus.com/payment-complete/">` specifies the return url. For more info - [Go Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-paypal-payment-form/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider also the [Auto return](http://www.paysketch.com/paypal-auto-return-url/) option: it allows you to set up an url for all buttons.

- Log in and click the Profile subtab under My Account.
- Click the Website Payment Preferences link under Selling Preferences.
- Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
- Enter the Return URL

> The Return URL will be applied universally to all Auto Return payments. This can be overridden by mentioning separate return URLs in the payment buttons that you’ve created in your PayPal profile

More info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7708419/1677209).