# How to configure paypal sandbox auto return URL?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, ubercart

I am using `ubercart` module in `Drupal`, and I need help to configure return `URL` from `PayPal sandbox`. I tried creating business account in https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/dashboard , but that also is not working.

Answer (score 56):

When you say you're unable to create a Business account what error are you receiving or are you unable to login? Please provide more details on this and feel free to contact me via the details in my profile.

Here are the steps to enable Auto Return in your test account.

- Log into https://developer.paypal.com
- Click Applications
- Click Sandbox accounts
- Expand the account in question
- Click Sandbox site
- Login to the test account
- Copy and paste "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments" into your browser
- Enable Auto Return and click Save
- Enter the Auto Return URL and click Save

Let me know if these steps give you any issues.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having the issue where the settings tabs load forever and never appear. Copying the URL to access the settings worked. I've had to do this for the IPN settings also [sandbox only]

Comment: When I enable Auto Return, click "save" and return to those preferences Auto Return is switched back to Off again. Why?

Comment: Having the same problem.

Comment: @van_folmert May be you didn't provide the return url

Comment: Thank you it really helped me out. Is incredible how is possible that sandbox is so out of date, nothing is working, the links are not shown and they have no intention to fix it...

Comment: Where is *Sandbox site* option?

Answer (score 6):

I was also facing similar issue. How I set the auto redirect URL in the sandbox mode is as following.

1. Login to the [sandbox.paypal.com](http://sandbox.paypal.com) using the sandbox business account example,

`xyz-facilitator@example.com`

there set Auto redirect to On, and Turn off *PayPal Account Optional* setting.

2. In the PayPal button (Form) code  use following for the business information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your sandbox account https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/
2. Click Seller tools
3. Selling Online section click Website preferences
4. Turn on Auto return
5. put your merchant URL e.g. http://localhost/drupal-project and save
6. You can also configure other preferences to your choice