# Paypal return url with variable

Tags: paypal

If i include some variables in "return" and send to paypal, how paypal will send back to me when i get back?

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value='http://www.xxx.xx/order/complete.jsp?ordercode=ABCD&cn=aa,bb'>
```

will paypal encode my URL to like this?

```
http://www.xxx.xx/order/complete.jsp?ordercode=ABCD&cn=aa%2Cbb
```

or this?

```
http://www.xxx.xx/order/complete.jsp?ordercode=ABCD&cn=aa,bb
```

Thanks.

Comment: you probably have to test : check your apache access log.

Comment: @theredled, thanks a lot .. i already checked and got the answer. :)

Comment: See this [question][1] which should answer it for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7642895/645583

Comment: I am sending multiple parameters with return url but when I am back to return url with token and payer id, I loose my sent variables? How do you get the variables then?

Comment: @Umar, which programming language are you using? I'm using java so i just simply use `request.getParameter(paramName);`

Comment: @Raymond I am using PHP and I fixed this issue by sending urlencoded return url to paypal