# Paypal Test account errors

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal sandbox in my project,when I submit paypal form with payment and product detail, It give me this error `This recipient is currently unable to receive money.` on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/
   My `paypal Form cmd value = _xclick-subscriptions`

any suggestion please!

Comment: have you set up a sandbox account to receive payments?

Comment: Yes I have test account at sandbox and was working fine, there is any limit of amount at Pyapal? in my test account I have $43,352.22  Balance.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're trying to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem with me, so I leave old test account and create a new test account at here for paypal sandbox testing.
      [Papal Developers](https://developer.paypal.com/)

and for more setting visit this link [Setting PayPal return URL and making it auto return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return)