# Paypal button with dropdown menu

Tags: paypal

I am new to paypal. I have a paypal payment button with a dropdown list which i have generated from paypal site. the drop down list contains three items my question is whenever a user buys an item by selecting from drop down list how should i know what he have chosen to buy. Does paypal returns data in success url

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the details of the transaction in your PayPal account, but if you want this information to be returned to your site, for example for keeping or automation purposes, you should enable auto return, for more info you can read here: [Setting PayPal return URL and making it auto return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return)