# paypal returnurl not working even if the auto Return is set to On

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have newly set up the sandbox test accounts.

The requirement is , user purchase click on payment we redirect user to paypal they can pay via credit card and then come pack to our site. On successful payment we are showing order confirmation page.

I can make successful transaction on paypal but it return to home page...

I have configured in my business account return url and PDT is also on.

Can someone guide me what I may be missing..kindly advice

Comment: There are two areas to set return url, on the method you are using to transfer Paypal (express checkout, buttons) and on the Paypal settings page. Check both. edit - check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return