# Paypal not posting data on Return url on mobile browsers

Tags: php, post, paypal

I am using html form to integrate Paypal and my form is as

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="admin@domain.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://domain.com/success" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://domain.com/fail/" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Please Click here to Complete Your Order" />
</form>
```

When I am testing this Website code on desktop browsers this is posting paypal data back on return url perfectly. But when I am testing same website code on my Mobile browser payapl is not posting back any data on return url. It just get back on return url without any data.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

do you get ANY kind of request on callback on mobile? You should log every POST request on callback page  and review them

also try with `notify_url` as well, IPN should be sent here

Answer (score 0):

Please set "no_note"
    
    
Please see following links
Link: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/html.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that you need to add this line to your code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, your solution didn't worked for me. Why you think no_note is the problem? Have you faced this issue? Did you solved such issue earlier?