# How to get the Customer email in the return page from Paypal?

Tags: paypal

I'm using the Buy Now with Paypal button in my site. I'd need, once payment has been done, to get on my return page the Customer's email. This way I can send to the customer the download link for the media I'm selling. What's the easiest way to achieve it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think Those links will help.
https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1291/How+do+I+auto-
return+my+customers+to+my+store+after+they+checkout+with+PayPal%3F

[Setting PayPal return URL and making it auto return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return)

Comment: Excuse me I was just going through the Developer docs. Would it be simpler if I just include an IPN message listener PHp page where I collect the customer's data (the email) ? Thanks