# ASP.NET receive a query string from paypal after payment

Tags: paypal, asp-classic, query-string, return-value

I have created a button that allows for users to pay via PayPal and it works,
however when I get back to my page I receive no **url query string to catch**.

Here is the current code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <button class="ato4" name="submit" type="image" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#CCC9BD';return true;" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='rgba(79,129,189,0.5)';return true;" style="cursor:pointer;float:right;margin-right:490px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">    
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="V84TB5GYULLYC">
    <font class="shadowfilter">תשלום דרך האינטרנט
      <br>
      <font style="color:green;">PAYPAL</font>
    </font>
  </button>
</form>
```

How do I make paypal automatically redirect to my website without pressing the **return** button that PayPal has on their website?

apparently there is an option for all pages to auto return to -> url . well it's not as good as an individual pages but it gives the result

Comment: Payment systems like PayPal usually expect an Endpoint *(basically an ASP page URL they can pass data to)* you would then in that page capture the data *(using `Request.Form`)* and process / update your database etc.

Comment: and thats exactrly what i do but there no data on the return and i use this methode for other pay site but find it no so easy for paypal...

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the configuration this time, either way its a question for PayPal support not [so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable auto return in your PayPal account, otherwise it will ignore the `return` field.

From the documentation (updated to reflect new layout):

> Auto Return is turned off by default.
>   To turn on Auto Return:
>
> 1. Log in to your PayPal account at https://www.paypal.com. 
>      The My Account Overview page appears.
> 2. Click the Profile subtab. 
>      The Profile Summary page appears.
> 3. Click the My Selling Tools link in the left column.
> 4. Under the Selling Online section, click the Update link in the row for Website Preferences.
>      The Website Payment Preferences page appears
> 5. Under Auto Return for Website Payments, click the On radio button to enable Auto 
>      Return.
> 6. In the Return URL field, enter the URL to which you want your payers redirected after 
>      they complete their payments. 
>      NOTE: PayPal checks the Return URL that you enter. If the URL is not properly formatted 
>      or cannot be validated, PayPal will not activate Auto Return.
> 7. Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click the Save button.

IPN is for instant payment notification.  It will give you more reliable/useful information than what you'll get from auto-return.

Documentation for IPN is here: https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/ipnguide.pdf

Online Documentation for IPN: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

The general procedure is that you pass a `notify_url` parameter with the request, and set up a page which handles and validates IPN notifications, and PayPal will send requests to that page to notify you when payments/refunds/etc. go through.  That IPN handler page would then be the correct place to update the database to mark orders as having been paid.

Ref.: [Setting PayPal return URL and making it auto return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return)

Comment: as i mention above i did the auto return but in order to return i need to press the button "return to...." after i or customer paid....which in my opinion no auto return.