# Capture PayPal return variable using PHP

Tags: php, html, paypal, payment

I am using PayPal Standard HTML form, and after the user has completed the transaction he/she is taken to the return url. I want to be able to identify the user email, the order number, and other information that may be available using php. In other words, I want to use the `GET method` to retrieve the variables in the URL

This is a recurring payment (subscription), and below is the html code.

```
  <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@merchant.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="test">
  <!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <!-- Identify the subscription. -->
  <input id="paymentName" type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1234">

  <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
  <input id="paymentPrice" type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
  <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">

  <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

  <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">

  <!-- Display the payment button. -->
  <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" style="width:240px;   border: none; height:50px"
  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-large.png"
  alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online"> 
</form>
```

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting PayPal return URL and making it auto return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return)

Comment: can u elaborate on paypal ipn

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: IPN is indeed the way you want to go here.  There are some good templates for it to get you started on GitHub / Packagist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already commented. You should use Instant Payment Notification (IPN).

[documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

Basically you need to set in your html form a field called "notifyurl", something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notifyurl"alue="http://www.example.com/ipn_listener.php">
```

For the ipn_listener.php you have sample code here (if PHP):

[Sample code for PHP](https://gist.github.com/xcommerce-gists/3440401#file-completelistener-php)

If you need to attach some specif information to the payment you can also use the paremeter "custom", and read it back in you ipn listener.