# Angular 2 paypal

Tags: angular, paypal

I am setting up a new ecommerce project with angular 2 and firebase. My issue is how to integrate a paypal button and when customers  click on it, they will be redirected to paypal and pay then redirect back to my site. 
At the moment I manage to get tnhem back either they pay or cancel with a given return url as instructed in this github repo: 
https://github.com/musale/angular2-paypal
The problem is how to get data from paypal to assure that payment was successful before we can proceed with the order. 
I understand that we can get them either by paypal IPN or PDT but dont know how to with angular 2 firebase. 
Solutions, examples or suggestions would be apreciated.

Comment: i think the solution is given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7708419/2036977

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for the solutions and here is our delayed solution: as Firebase controls the backend, it is impossible to setup a payment system on it, we setup a light-weight nodejs express server hosted on google cloud platform which can communicate with paypal to receive IPN data from paypal each time our customer makes a payment. The IPN data will be used to check with realtime data from Firebase and updates payment status to client side.

Comment: Is it possible to handle payments entirely on the frontend without any changes to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

After user finish paying in PayPal, you can send them back to your website, then put loading message on the screen. Meanwhile you will have interval that will ask your server if the transaction was completed.

Using PayPal IPN, PayPal will make http call to desired URL after a transaction was made, then you need to pick up the POST data that contain the info about the transaction, send it back to PayPal to verified that they send it, and after that do what you want with the information.

- When you create the form for the PayPal button use 'custom' hidden fields for identification of the transaction (for example it can be user ID) PayPal we'll send this data back with the IPN so when you pick it up you can tie it to the correct user.
- You need to define your IPN URL inside your PayPal settings