# Angula2 Paypal Integration

Tags: angular, paypal

i am trying to setting up an ecommerce carting project using angular2, So i need your help to integrate a paypal paymnet module, when a customer click on the paypal checkout button, they will be redirected to paypal, after the payment process should redirect back to my application.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885352/angular-2-paypal and mentioned links there.

Comment: but there is no explanation about how to implement paypal module in Angula2, actually i am expecting this..thanks for your reply!

Comment: welcome, wish i could help you .

Comment: check this repo https://github.com/musale/angular2-paypal, tell me if you need an example of express checkout payment, I'm working on it right now

Comment: @Victor Bredihin , Please provide me an example of express checkout payment, Thanks for your great support!

Comment: no problem, I will finish it today and give you an example