# Analytics not tracking all conversions | Paypal Autoreturn?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using WooComm with PayPal as my default method. I'm deploying Google analytics through Google tag manager (GTM4WP).

I'm seeing several orders just not being logged in GA. Some come in, some don't and I just don't know how to resolve it.

We have 2 websites with the same Paypal, I heard a bit about auto-return needing to be enabled but I don't know what return path to use as I have two different sites and one Paypal - also will it really solve the issue.

Any help here would be great.

Thanks!

Nitesh

Comment: another possibility is that the user might be blocking ga scripts.

Comment: this might help with the autoreturn. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return Once you enable it you can send a parameter to where you want it to return(website a or website b) to so just add it to both your checkout forms. Then make sure you add the proper tags to this page and you should capture all of them