# How to speed up auto return to my site after PayPal payment

Tags: django, paypal

I am creating a website through which people can buy tickets via paypal – I want to send a confirmation email once the payment is complete.

I already set up auto return.

My problem is that it takes too long to redirect – I'm afraid that the users will click off the page before it is redirected and before the email is sent.

Is there a way to make the process faster, i.e allow me to send the email as soon as the payment is confirmed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting PayPal return URL and making it auto return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear - I already turned on auto return and got it to work. It's just that it takes very long to redirect, and I'm afraid that people will click off. Is there an earlier step where I could send the email?

Comment: you should use the IPN for confirming the payment and sending out the email https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/